# Minesweeper neighbors reveals blanks but not the numbers

Tags: java

[image]

```
public void revealCells(int row, int column) {
    if (row < 0 || row >= cells.length|| column < 0 || column >= cells[0].length)
        return;

    Cell cell = cells[row][column]; // now we are safe, so fetch the cell
    if(cell instanceof MineCell)
        return;   

    else if(cell.getMineCount() == 0 && !(cell.isRevealed())){
        cell.reveal();
        // call recursive with coordinates, not cells
        revealCells(row-1,column-1);
        revealCells(row-1,column);
        revealCells(row-1,column+1);
        revealCells(row,column-1);
        revealCells(row,column+1);
        revealCells(row+1,column-1);
        revealCells(row+1,column);
        revealCells(row+1,column+1);
    }
}
```

When I click all the blank all revealed but not the numbers. Attached an image so that you can see what I'm looking for

Comment: `if(cell.getMineCount() == 0`. That seems to cause only blank cells to reveal. This seems obvious, so what's your question?

Comment: Likely you need to call cell.reveal() before that if